# Exit shell script if file doesn't exist

Tags: shell, file, ksh

Ive got a .sql job which creates files depending on certain criteria, it writes these with a prefix of TEMP_ as we then have an adaptor that picks up the files and we dont want them picked up before writing is complete.
I need to put a post job in place which renames these files, i have it set up with a number of other job but they all create the files each time they run. This job only creates the files sometimes it runs, depending on the data in the system.
I need to do a check if the file exists and then exit if no file exists.

Ive found a few examples but they all seem to fail, this is where i have got to which i thought was checking if no file, if no file then exit but it fails and displays:
"syntax error at line 16: `TEMP_SUBCON*.csv' unexpected"

This is what i have currently with line 16 being the first line - Above that is just comments:

```
    if [[ ! -f $OUT_DIR -name TEMP_SUBCON*.csv ]] ; then
    exit $?
    fi
    
    TEMP_DATA_FILE=$(find $OUT_DIR -name TEMP_SUBCON_QTY_output*.csv)
    DATA_FILE=$(basename $TEMP_DATA_FILE | cut -c6-)
    
    echo $TEMP_DATA_FILE
    echo $DATA_FILE

## Rename the file name, remove the phrase TEMP_, so that EAI can pick the file ##
mv $TEMP_DATA_FILE $OUT_DIR/$DATA_FILE
```

Can you help guide what ive done incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: `-f $OUT_DIR -name TEMP_SUBCON*.csv` looks like it was lifted from an invocation of `find`, that's not valid syntax for `[[...]]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it right, you want to find the files with TEMP_ prefix in your $OUT_DIR, and then if any rename them without the prefix. Then that should do the trick

```
for file in $OUT_DIR/TEMP_SUBCON_*.txt; do
    if [[ -e $file ]]; then
        mv $file $OUT_DIR/${file#*SUBCON_}
    fi
done
exit
```

It will go through the directory finding each TEMP_ file and rename them without it. If there is none, it won't do anything.

Comment: Thanks @Andre Gelinas
Have tried that (Well a slightly modified version as it should only rename files beginning TEMP_SUBCON however i get the error:
mv: cannot stat `/opt/scripts/data/out/TEMP_SUBCON*.csv': No such file or directory

Any ideas?

Comment: good comment. I've edited the answer.

Comment: No errors, it didnt rename anything and then i realised the outputs are actually .txt so ive changed the .csv to .txt in above example but now the files are just disappearing.
If i remove the post job i can see the files are created but with the job they are being moved or deleted somehow. 
I did try amending your code to have mv $file $OUT_DIR/${file#*_} in case they were being written to another directory but no luck, same result the files just disappear

Comment: can you give a real example of filenames ?

Comment: Sure, filenames are TEMP_SUBCON_DATE_output20210922.txt and TEMP_SUBCON_QTY_output20210922.txt

Comment: Edited to reflect. That should leave you with QTY_output20210922.txt and DATE_output20210922.txt. Another thing, the file were probably move to wherever directory the script was start with since the path was deleted...my bad.

Comment: Unfortunately this still causes the files to disappear, do i need to keep the $OUT_DIR in the mv line?

Comment: see my last edited comment

Comment: Apologies, for whatever reason i hadnt grabbed the most recent.
This is doing exactly as you have highlighted, 
My goal was to get it to be SUBCON_DATE_output20210922 so i have changed it to:

`for file in $OUT_DIR/TEMP_*.txt; do
    if [[ -e $file ]]; then
        mv $file $OUT_DIR/${file#*TEMP_}
    fi
done
exit`

Is there anything wrong with how ive modified your code? This is brilliant by the way , solves my issue

Comment: Nothing wrong, glad that it works.

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is not valid for the `[[ ... ]]` test.

Why not use the result of the subsequent `find` command to check if there were any matching files in the specified directory instead, and quit if no files are returned (in other words, quit if the result variable is empty)?

Example:

```
TEMP_DATA_FILE=$(find $OUT_DIR -name "TEMP_SUBCON_QTY_output*.csv" )
if [[ -z ${TEMP_DATA_FILE:=""} ]]  ; then
   exit 1
fi
```

Note 1: you should quote the pattern argument for the `find` command as shown.

Note 2:  it is useful to use `set -u` in your ksh scripts to cause ksh to abort if variables are unitialized when used (often the cause of errors) , instead of using a default value. However, if you use use `set -u` then in any test you should explicitly give your own default value. That is the reason for using ${TEMP_DATA_FILE:=""} instead of ${TEMP_DATA_FILE} - to support the often very useful `set -u` option. Even when you do not use `set -u` the ${TEMP_DATA_FILE:=""} inside tests makes it explicit what should happen instead of relying on implicit behaviour.

Note 3: you should use `set -x` when debugging and study every line of the output, it will show you exactly what commands ran with which arguments and what was the result. This helps you to learn how to code in ksh and similar shells.

Comment: Thanks @mao - I had tried various derivations from guides online and that was just my latest so not surprised its not valid.
Thanks for the example, when i try that though it still errors, this time it doesnt give me any sort of error message it just displays FAILED in the log. 
Full Code is now:
`TEMP_DATA_FILE=$(find $OUT_DIR -name TEMP_SUBCON_QTY_output*.csv)
if [[ -z ${TEMP_DATA_FILE:=""} ]]  ; then
   exit 1
fi

DATA_FILE=$(basename $TEMP_DATA_FILE | cut -c6-)

echo $TEMP_DATA_FILE
echo $DATA_FILE
mv $TEMP_DATA_FILE $OUT_DIR/$DATA_FILE
exit $?`

Comment: `${TEMP_DATA_FILE:=""}` is a bit weird here.  There's no point making the assignment if the script is going to exit, so you might as well just write `"${TEMP_DATA_FILE}"`

Comment: Thanks @WilliamPursell , have tried with your suggestion and also get a fail.
Code tried is:
`TEMP_DATA_FILE=$(find $OUT_DIR -name TEMP_SUBCON_QTY_output*.csv)
if [[ -z "${TEMP_DATA_FILE}" ]]  ; then
   exit 1
fi

DATA_FILE=$(basename $TEMP_DATA_FILE | cut -c6-)

echo $TEMP_DATA_FILE
echo $DATA_FILE
## Rename the file name, remove the phrase TEMP_, so that EAI can pick the file ##
mv $TEMP_DATA_FILE $OUT_DIR/$DATA_FILE`

Log information no longer displays an error but does display a status of failed whereas i would expect/need it to Success